# how to pass variable to Javascript Namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I have created a Javascript namespace like so:

```
var MyApp = function() {
      return {
        someFunction : function(x) {}
             alert(MyApp.y);
      }
}();
```

This allows me to do this:

```
MyApp.someFunction(x);
```

I would like to be able to do the following:

`MyApp.y = "test"` so that my someFunction can access this variable Y.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I'd like to keep my NS syntax intact so a solution that works with my example code would be nice.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're putting someFunction in an enclosure? You can't pass in new variables to that enclosure once you've made it as far as I know, but you could access global variables of course. If you don't *need* the enclosure however you can do `this.someFunction = function(x) ...` instead of the `return` block. Also at a guess you probably want to `new` that function when you're storing it in `MyApp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you described should work. (Except you have a syntax error and an unused argument `x`.)

```
var MyApp = function() {
  return {
    someFunction : function(x) {
         alert(MyApp.y);
    }
  }
}();
MyApp.y = 'test';
MyApp.someFunction() // alerts 'test'
```

Another approach is to treat your outer function more like a constructor and pass y as a closure:

```
var MyApp = (function (y) {
    return {
        y: y,
        someFunction: function () {
            alert(MyApp.y); // or alert(this.y)
        }
    }
} ('test'));
MyApp.someFunction(); // alerts 'test'
```

Comment: you're right, it does. Seems like I missed something minor in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would go with something like this:

```
var MyApp = function() {
    var _y = "default value";
    return {
        someFunction: function(x) {
            console.log(_y);
        },
        setY: function (y) {
            _y = y;
        }
    }
}();
```

This will mean that it is safe to call `MyApp.someFunction()` before assigning a value to `y`. It also means that the contents of the variable is maintained within the namespace's scope, e.g.

```
console.log(MyApp._y); // undefined
```

Here would be how to use it:

```
MyApp.someFunction(); // "default value"
MyApp.setY("new value");
MyApp.someFunction(); // "new value"
```

Comment: @akellehe why? JavaScript isn't Python. Using an underscore won't (by itself) prevent the variable from showing up in a `for…in` loop or being true when he runs `MyApp.hasOwnProperty('_y')`. Private members in JavaScript are just variables of the constructor. They're only accessible by private and privileged methods. [Ref](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) I'm not against this approach, I just don't see the point of the underscore, and OP doesn't ask for the value to be private.

Comment: The underscore makes the private variable much more readable.  When you see it somewhere it's scope is immediately understood.  It's very easy to tell apart from local variables in class/instance methods.